# MongoDB: поиск подстроки игнорируя е и ё

Tags: регулярные-выражения, mongodb

Необходимо реализовать поиск документов в MongoDB по значению строкового поля (`start with`) без учета регистра и считать "е" и "ё" равнозначными, т.е. на запрос "самоле" должны находиться как "самолет" так и "самолёт".